# Not able to import python tty module in raspberry pi yocto build

Tags: python, linux, yocto, tty, meta-raspberrypi

**Description**

Error while python tty module.

How to enable this module in yocto build ?

**Environment**

```
root@raspberrypi3-64:~# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi3-64 5.4.83-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 20 09:59:41 UTC 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

**Log**

```
root@raspberrypi3-64:~# python3
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec  7 2020, 22:33:43) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tty'
>>> 
root@raspberrypi3-64:~#
```

**Expected output**

The tty module should be imported similar to the following Log from the ubuntu 18.04 host

```
~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tty
>>> 
~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python3` recipe is a bit different than others, so it's not always straightforward to find which packages it builds and their name.

For Python standard libraries, such as `tty`, `logging`, `2to3`, `datetime`, one has to read the `python3-manifest.json` file used in the `python3` recipe, see http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3/python3-manifest.json?h=master

There, you can see that `tty.py` is part of the `terminal` dictionary. All first level key (`terminal` included) in the "root" dictionary will be the suffix for the package that will be created. In `terminal` case, it'll thus be `python3-terminal`. Which means if one wants `tty` module on their target, they should add the `python3-terminal` to their image recipe.

This specific logic of package splitting the standard libraries of Python was a consequence of Python with all its libraries being outrageously big for embedded systems where usually the set of libraries used can be defined and fixed or updated by hand.